# How to point shared load balancer http/https port to specific port of my Jelastic Docker container

Tags: jelastic

My app listens stuff on port 8082 (or whatever one).
I want to configure shared load balancer to route all requests from 443 port (HTTPS) to this port. As far as I understand, this is done by some Jelastic magic during container creation. So far so good, everything worked fine.
But after I've updated base image for my Docker app (from openjre-152 to openjre-171 or something like this) SLB stopped to re-route traffic to my app.
Is there way to change/setup this internal configuration manually without environment re-creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `JELASTIC_EXPOSE` as written in [docs](https://docs.jelastic.com/container-ports), however, it's not clear that your traffic will be redirected and ssl-terminated by SLB.

Comment: Please, let us know if you have solved your problem.
Also, specify, what was not clear in the docs.

Comment: It is not clear which port on SLB mapped to port in the containers. For the first it looked like JELASTIC_EXPOSE key is used to direct port mapping. It would be nice to have explanation — "incoming requests to ports 80 and 443 will be mapped to container port specified in JELASTIC_EXPOSE variable" and have corresponding arrow in the picture. Also it'd be nice to have note about SSL termination like "https traffic would be terminated on SLB and your node will get http traffic".